# Passing multiple parameter through razor asp-route

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core

I have problem with my code about razor asp-route.  I have model which handles the `get` and `set` of data and then I need to use my model as a parameter to pass to my controller.  Here is my code below:

**Controller:**

```
    public IActionResult getEmployeeLedger(spGetLedger ledger)
    {
        //Everything is here
    }
```

**Model:**

```
public class Ledger
{
    public List<spGetLedger> enumledger { get; set; }
    public spGetLedger ledger { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```html
<a asp-controller="Ledger" asp-action="getEmployeeLedger" asp-route-ledger.EmployeeID="@item.EmployeeID" asp-route-ledger.LoanTypeID="@item.LoanTypeID">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EducationalLoan)</a>
```

Is it possible to use this kind of way `asp-route-model.modelID` or is there any way that I could possible achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: With your current code/model? No. Route parameters are for routes and query parameter only. If you want to bind query parameters to a model you need to use the `[Bind("Property1", "Property2", "Property3")]` on the model, where `PropertyX` is the name of the property (and hence has to be name of the query parameter too), which means your route setup would need to be `asp-route-propertyX`

Comment: Sorry I'm still a newbie with asp right now. Would you mind give me a sample code? I don't really understand what you said about [Bind("Something")]

Comment: @AlvinQuezon do you have to? cant you just use begin.form() ?